# How to grab the upper case in Py3?

Tags: string, python-3.x

For example, I have a text like this:

```
This is my String
```

I would like to grab `TS`, I would like to grab the upper case only.

Comment: "Grap"? Do you mean grab? grep? grip? get? filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `str.isupper` predicate method in conjunction with `filter` in order to filter out the uppercase characters.

If you want the result to be a string, not a sequence, join it with `''.join`.

```
>>> print(''.join(filter(str.isupper, "This is my String")))
TS
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to grab this in a way that allows for keeping each letter in a list, tuple, etc. But here is a way to do so using a list expression:

```
    import string
    >>> [c for c in "This is my String" if c in string.ascii_uppercase]
    ['T', 'S']
```

Also, maybe you would like to store the upper case characters in different ways, or immediately do things with them. A for loop can work well for this, such as:

```
    for c in 'This is my String':
        if c in string.ascii_uppercase: print(c) # Or do something else.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, to build on KOS's post, if you don't mind a list,

```
>>> s = 'This is a test String'
>>> print(list(filter(str.isupper, s)))
['T', 'S']
```